# How to hide grid and show only zeroline in QCustomPlot?

Tags: qt, qtgui, qcustomplot

Is there any way of showing zeroline in QCustomPlot while hiding grid? I have tried hiding grid with following line:

```
ui->customPlot->xAxis->grid()->setVisible(false);
ui->customPlot->yAxis->grid()->setVisible(false);
```

But this also hides the zerolines. I need to keep zerolines visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `Qt::NoPen` to `QCPGrid::setPen`/`setSubGridPen`, but not `setZeroLinePen`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Current->xAxis->grid()->setSubGridVisible(false); 
Current->yAxis->grid()->setSubGridVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//grid handling
bool isGridLineVisible() const;
void setGridLineVisible(bool visible = true);
```